# How can I pass an argument to paintComponent in order to call it in a different class?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, custom-painting

In my main class I have the following code to load an image from my machine and display it on the frame to draw things on it:

```
public class ShowMap extends JPanel {

    private static final int WIDTH = 1340;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 613;

    public void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MAP");
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("map.png"));
        panel.add(label);
    }
}
```

The image I am loading is a map where I would like to indicate the position of some objects by drawing points in the right coordinates. So it is important here to dictate to the `DrawPoint` class (below) what coordinates should get the point.

Also, I would greatly appreciate an explanation of how to erase a point that has been drawn.

My search led me to the following, but as soon as I add `int coordx, int coordy` to the arguments of the method, it is no more highlighted, and I don't know how to call this method in `ShowMap` while passing the coordinates as arguments.

```
public class DrawPoint extends JPanel {

    private int coordx;
    private int coordy;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g, int coordx, int coordy){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(coordx,coordy,8,8);
    }
}
```

Comment: First, you can’t - and shouldn’t. Paint should paint the current state of the component, which means you should be changing a state variable of the component and then calling repaint. Second, you simply call super.paintComponent, it will clear context so you can paint on it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demonstration of what MadProgrammer wrote in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453884/how-can-i-pass-an-argument-to-paintcomponent-in-order-to-call-it-in-a-different#comment93781379_53453884) : "should be changing a state variable of the component and then calling repaint" :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SwingTest extends JFrame {

    private static final int SIZE = 300;
    private DrawPoint drawPoint;

    public SwingTest()  {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        drawPoint = new DrawPoint();
        drawPoint.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SIZE, SIZE));
        add(drawPoint);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    //demonstrate change in DrawPoint state
    private void reDraw() {

        Random rnd = new Random();
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, e -> { //periodically change coordinates and repaint
            drawPoint.setCoordx(rnd.nextInt(SIZE));
            drawPoint.setCoordy(rnd.nextInt(SIZE));
            drawPoint.repaint();
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->    new SwingTest().reDraw());
    }
}

class DrawPoint extends JPanel {

    private int coordx, coordy;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(coordx,coordy,8,8);
    }

    //use setters to change the state 
    void setCoordy(int coordy) {    this.coordy = coordy; }
    void setCoordx(int coordx) {this.coordx = coordx;}
}
```

Comment: c0der, would you please explain how I could do this on a loaded image from my machine?

Comment: Assuming your image is `Image bgImage` draw it by `g.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, this);`. If you need help with it post a new question and leave me a message here so I can try and help.

Comment: I posted a new question, link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462122/draw-objects-on-a-loaded-image-in-java.
Thank you for all the help.